# How do you calculate this infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n+1}{n-p}}{(4^n)(2n+1)(1.25)^{2n+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Evaluate the  infinite series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n+1}{n-p}}{(4^n)(2n+1)(1.25)^{2n+1}}$$

On a calculator, for $p=0$ this tends to $1$. For $p=1$ it tends to $\frac{1}{12}$. For all values of $p$ I checked the result was a reciprocal of a natural number. How would you calculate this without a calculator for single values of $p$ and for any $p$ in general (natural numbers).

Comment: Where did you get this series from?

Comment: A beginning would be to collect the $n$th powers to get $$\frac45 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n-p} (\tfrac{4}{25})^n $$

Comment: It originated from the trigonometric power formulas and was modified a bit for my use. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n+1}{n-p}}{(4^n)(2n+1)(1.25)^{2n+1}}&=
2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n+1}{n+p+1}}{(2n+1)(2.5)^{2n+1}}\\
&=\frac{4}{5}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n}{n+p}x^n}{n+p+1}
\end{align}$$
with $x=4/25$.
For $p=0$, recall that, for $|x|<1/4$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{2n}{n}x^n}{n+1} = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}$$
(see the g.f.of the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)). Extend this identity and show that for non-negative integer $p$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{2n}{n+p}x^n}{n+p+1} = \left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}\right)^{2p+1}\cdot \frac{x^p}{2p+1}$$

Comment: Is there any way to extend or modify the Catalan Numbers' property to find values for any p?

Comment: @Nimish See my edit.

Comment: Sorry about asking this so late but is there a more general extension for the Catalan Numbers' to even include types like this: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n}{n}(x^n)}{(2n)}$? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nimish We have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n}{n}(x^n)}{(2n)}=\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}\right)$.